# How to identify an element through xpath from the HTML with multiple partially similar Link Text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Wants to locate element by the name which is defined,

I am using by following `contains` syntax, But not achieving target element

```
String deviceName = "AutoTest";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='noDecoration addPointer'][contains(text(),'"+deviceName+"')]"));
```

As we can see, first data contains value which is given in variable. Every time it takes first element in which it found the same value. But, I wants to locate  element with defined value. How to trace it ?

HTML :

```
<div class="deviceName truncate">
    <a class="noDecoration addPointer" ng-if="itemDeviceType" ng-href="" href="">AutoTest</a>
</div>
```

[image: Wants to Locate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared it seems to be an *Angular* element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait*. Now, if you are going to identify elements in the similar fashion multiple times, you can create a `function()` which will accept a `String` e.g. **AutoTest** to locate the desired element as follows :

```
public void locateElement(String deviceType)
{
    WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='deviceName truncate']/a[@class='noDecoration addPointer'][normalize-space()='" + deviceType + "']")));
    //you can do anything with the element
}
```

Now, you can call this function with the required `String` argument whenever and wherever required as follows :

```
locateElement("AutoTest")
locateElement("AutoTest003")
locateElement("AutoTest032")
```

Comment: @IshitaShah Let me know if you have any query/counter questions.

Comment: It seems you have edited answer. I have refer it again, But its not working.

Comment: @IshitaShah **not working** doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your exact _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ along with your current code block and the error stack trace.

Comment: It make sense with my question and issue. There is no need of manual steps for it.  For your information, there is no such exception also. It takes other element which contains like AutoTest %

Comment: I have added this syntax - normalize-space() in my existing code, and it works with : //a[@class='noDecoration addPointer'][normalize-space()='" + deviceName + "']

Comment: @IshitaShah Look out at the attributes **ng-if** and **ng-href** they are purely **Angular**. You to fall back on the waiter sooner or later.

Comment: Yeah I know it contains AngularJS call. And my web application is based on it. Every time I have to wait, and it does not work  with Explicit wait. For that I have separate utility to wait until page load.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the problem. The problem isn't that the element needs to be waited on... if that were the case then the first element wouldn't have been found at all. The problem is the use of `contains()`. This whole problem could have been solved simply by using `By.linkText()` without the lengthy and complicated XPaths.

Comment: @JeffC Seems you need to understand the representation of _HTML DOM_ and how _Selenium_ works. Please read the docs and refrain from _downvoting accepted answers_ which is counter productive to StackOverflow community. If you have any question feel free to raise it. StackOverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Yeah... you keep saying that but that doesn't disprove what I stated. Your answer didn't work because of the wait. OP already stated that he is getting the first element but wants a different one. Your answer worked because of the `normalize-space()=` (similar to `text()=`) but you didn't explain that at all... did you even realize why your answer worked?

Comment: @JeffC OP understood the solution well and responded accordingly. It's unfortunate that you claim to be downvoting _Selenium_ related _questions_ and _answers_ for 4 years now on stackoverflow and still didn't understand the usage of `normalize-space()`

Comment: One last attempt... the vast majority of your answer is explaining waits and why a wait will fix the problem. The reason your answer worked had nothing to do with waits. It also had nothing to do with `normalize-space()`... `text()` or `By.linkText()` would have worked properly also given the HTML. You have a tendency in your answer to overexplain things that have nothing to do with the question or the answer.

Comment: @JeffC I am afraid, you need to read the docs to explore how elements are represented within the _HTML DOM_ i.e. _HTML5_ and _Angular_ elements both and how to handle them. Read my Answer carefully again and again you will understand why an waiter is needed. Simply downvoting doesn't adds any value to any of the QA/discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Xpath is doing what you're expecting it to.  If you want to locate an element by multiple predicates, this is the format:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='noDecoration addPointer' and contains(text(),'"+deviceName+"')]"));
```

You may have to combine this with a wait, as other answers suggest.

Comment: Tried with combine condition, Its working similarly as previous.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the issue you're facing here.  Are you saying it always returns the first AutoTest element it comes to?  That makes sense as you're using a contains predicate, and "AutoTest" which is within all the elements you're trying to locate.  Use text()='AutoTest' if you only want to get the one that contains exactly AutoTest?

Comment: I can't use any static text, Its dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **contains** in your locator. That is why it is happening. Just remove contains and pass the exact name of the device.

```
By.xpath("//a[@class='noDecoration addPointer'][@text()='"+deviceName+"')]
```

If you use it will select all the anchor tags that having the passed device name. In your case, all the device name contain 'AutoTest'. That is why you are getting the first element instead of the expected one.

Comment: Variable contains dynamic value.

Comment: I have provided you answer by assuming that you have the list of device names. Then it makes no sense what you are trying to achieve. Well, in that case, you have to find all elements and then traverse through each of them to find the expected one.

Comment: Its doing in that way only. :)

Comment: This answer is exactly right... the reason you are having the problem is because you are looking for "AutoTest" using `contains()` in a list where all devices contain the string "AutoTest". You need to search for the exact device name using `.='deviceName'`.